# Fedora 25 tar errors from backup script aquota.user: Cannot time Operation not permitted

Tags: file-permissions, tar, quota

We just upgraded to Fedora 25 and re-enabled our tar/gzip backups to our Drobo units.

These errors just started happening after re-enabling the backups.

```
gzip: stdout: Input/output error
/bin/tar: Child returned status 1
/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

STANDARD OUTPUT:
Backed up /home to /drobo/home.tgz

Backup of /home/users FAILED

Backed up /home/users to
home-users-FAILED.tgz
/bin/tar: home/users/aquota.user: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
```

I know that the aquota.user file is set to be immutable:

```
lsattr aquota.user 

----i--A------e---- aquota.user
```

So I tried this:

```
# chattr -iAe aquota.user
chattr: Operation not permitted while setting flags on aquota.user
```

So I tried to add these flags to the tar command in our backup script:

```
--no-overwrite-dir --preserve-permissions
```

The errors continue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a reply from one of the GNU tar maintainers:

> Exclude-related options are "[position-sensitive](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Position_002dSensitive-Options.html)";  you need to move
>   the 'home/users' argument to the end of the command (after
>   --exclude=aquota.user).

So in our `/etc/drobo-backup.conf` file, we can't have any exclude options in the backup directive like we had:

```
backup = /home/users --atime-preserve --exclude=aquota.user  --exclude=.gvfs --exclude=--exclude-ignore-recursive=S.gpg-agent
```

Once we changed it to simply:

```
backup = /home/users
```

And placed them in this directive:

```
tarargs= --one-file-system --warning=no-file-ignored --warning=no-file-changed --warning=no-file-removed --use-compress-program=pigz  --atime-preserve --exclude=.gvfs
```

No more errors. So I simply created a separate cron backup to backup just the `aquota.user` file.

Answer (score 1):

The file belongs to your quota system and you should leave it untouched. Just add that file your exclude list in your `tar` command.